SpEL expression involving multiple beans
The beans are defined thus:
   <bean id="defaultSourceMetaData" class="com.example.metadata.SourceMetaData">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${source.name}"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="reconSourceMetaData" class="com.example.metadata.SourceMetaData" factory-method="extractData">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${source.metadata.query}"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="sourceProvider" class="com.example.file.FileSourceProvider">
        <property name="sourceMetaData" value="#{ reconSourceMetaData != null ? reconSourceMetaData : defaultSourceMetaData }"/>
   </bean>

We know, that the reconSourceMetaData is null -- because the query initializing it returns an empty set. But the defaultSourceMetaData is not being created -- and the program fails with
Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean' to required type 'com.example.metadata.SourceMetaData' for property 'sourceMetaData': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

If I replace the SpEL-expression with a direct reference to the default bean:
<property name="sourceMetaData" ref="defaultSourceMetaData"/>

the defaultSourceMetaData-bean is initialized, and the property is initialized correctly. But I do need the initialization to be conditional -- what's wrong with the syntax I'm using?

reconSourceMetaData isn't null, it references a NullBean. I would suggest writing a simple FactoryBean for this, returning either one or the other instead of programming in XML.

reconSourceMetaData is null -- the SQL-query, that could initialize it, returns empty set -- and the factory method returns null. That's not the question. The question is, why is not the defaultSourceMetaData instantiated -- and assigned to sourceMetaData, when a SpEL-expression is used?

Read, please read. It isn't null it is NullBean hence it doesn't work in a  SPEL expression. I suggest to add another factory which selects either of the beans and not to program in XML (which is generally a bad idea anyway).

If comparing to null is not the right way, what's the method to check, whether a bean is a NullBean -- inside a SpEL-expression?

Actually, according to documentation, any instance of NullBean returns true, when compared to null. So the existing expression should work... Back to the question: why does not it?

In regular Java yes, SPEL not so sure (and from the outcome here it doesn't it clearly sees the NullBean). You can add an instance of check (but as stated you are now starting to program in SPEL just add a factory to select either, that way you don't need SPEL and just have java).

I suspect (but I would have to dive deep into SPEL parsing) that the == does not call equals actually but does a real equality check. You can try using Objects.equals which should delegate to the equals call eventually.

Thanks to the hints provided by @m-deinum, I got it: use the .equals method instead of comparing to null. The below expression works now, just as the previous syntax used to work with Spring-4.x:
#{reconSourceMetaData.equals(null) ? defaultSourceMetaData : reconSourceMetaData}

